# Why did Injured tell the other players to focus on trapping the ball cleanly?

Tags: serhiy-zhadan, ukrainian-language, voroshilovgrad

In *Voroshilovgrad*, when Herman and his team were about to play soccer against the "gas guys", Injured urged his teammates to focus on trapping the ball cleanly:

> "All right, guys," he said, "focus on trapping the ball cleanly. Got it?"
> "Got it, Injured," Vasya Negative answered for all of us.

Why did he consider that the most important thing to focus on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the original what Injured says is

> — Значить, так, — сказав, — усім відпрацьовувати. Ясно?

Here *відпрацьовувати* means pretty much *work your ass off*. Nothing about the ball.

In Russian translation the word is *отрабатывать*. A very closely looking word, *обрабатывать* (just one letter difference), in the soccer context indeed means to handle the ball. Looks very much like a mistranslation.